# Formatting Seconds into Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds for SQL Report Builder Y-Axis Label

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, number-formatting

**The Problem**

I cannot get the y-axis of a SQL Report Builder graph to represent numbers as 'dd HH:mm:ss'.

[image: Graph]

**Background**

I am doing some SQL reports and the report I'm working on is meant to generate a stacked area graph of data based on the amount of time that a document spends in each department.

e.g.
Document 1 was in Dept. A for 30s, Dept. B for 25s and Dept. C for 90s, total: 145s.
Document 2 was in Dept. A for 20s, Dept. B for 30s and Dept. C for 80s, total: 130s.
...etc...

So a user will be able to judge how long documents spend in each department, given there are hundreds or thousands of documents.

I am able to successfully query this data, and as expected, the total seconds is coming out in the order of millions due to the amount of documents that have been recorded.  This is also due to the fact that the data I'm using is dummy-data, so I want to make sure that any formatting I do on this number (when it comes to graphing) will be able to manage numbers in the order of hundreds.

**What I Tried**

- Use of Custom number formatting in Vertical Axis Properties > Number > Category: Custom.  I tried using Format(DateAdd(...), "HH:mm:ss") which would produce HH:mm:ss okay, but I couldn't adjust it to give days.
- Explicitly using 'dd HH:mm:ss' in the Custom number formatting box simply wrote that string along the intervals on the axis.  I suspect that this is because the data type of the axis is integer, not datetime or date.
- Rewriting the SQL Query to output the seconds as the desired format.  The reason this doesn't work is because the format is then only associated for each item in the table which doesn't solve the problem.
- Adjusting the interval type of the axis, but again, this doesn't work because of the datatype.

I may have missed some attempted solutions due to the amount of time this has taken.  However, any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work for seconds under 24 hours (SSRS):

`Format(DateAdd(interval, units, datetime), format)`

e.g.

`Format(DateAdd("s", 86399, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")` gives `23:59:59`

To solve dealing with times greater than 24 hours, I went back to SQL Management Studio and changed my query to produce a **datetime** rather than an **integer**.  This gave Reporting Services the ability to format that as needed.  The SQL query became:

`DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(WorkTime + IdleTime), '00:00:00') as Total`

By using the `DATEADD` function in SQL, the datetime could then be used immediately in Reporting Services.  I then changed the vertical axis settings for the graph:

- Axis options back to default values
- Under Vertical Axis Properties > Number, select Custom
- In the Custom Format box, type: `dd:HH:mm:ss`

As the input datatype is now naturally datetime, Reporting Services will handle it itself.  This works a charm, although the interval type will probably default to a day, therefore not showing *accurate* data, a drill down report can manage specific numbers.  Furthermore, smaller times "*...in the order of hundreds...*" will be dealt with, with example times reading: `00:04:59:59`.